# NGRX Presentational Components Passing Events to Container

Tags: angular, ionic2, ngrx

I have read a few articles about dividing components into "Container" and "Presentation" components when using NGRX (or Redux in general). The idea is to separate out the knowledge of the Store and how to get the data into the Container and have the Presentational components only know about how to present specific data.

Using Ionic, it seems like the page is the natural choice for the Container object but I am getting into situations that feel contrary to Redux style. When I have a composition of components, i.e. sub-components that have sub-components, and they need to send an action back to the store I find myself having to add @Output to any component in the middle so that it can make it all the way back to the container. This seems to be against Redux style so is there a better way to do this (or am I misunderstanding something about Containers vs. Presentations)?

Ex.

```
* StorePage - a Container component that knows about my NGRX store to get Items
  * ItemList - a Presentation component that displays the list of ItemCards
    * ItemCard - a Presentation component that displays info about the Item and allows you to add to cart.
```

In this case ItemCard has an @Output EventEmitter that ItemList catches and then ItemList has an @Output EventEmitter to pass it up to StorePage.

Comment: I'm currenly using ngrx/redux and found the same doubt as you. What I'm trying to do is split my component in those that are only for present data (example: render a list of items, or show the cover picture from a page with some data) and those that have to de al with state changes (example: a component where the usar can toggle a favorite state from a page). Those, call services that later dispatch actions.